# Adobe Muse: Element positioning with fluid scaling

Tags: image, adobe, scaling, fluid, muse

I'm trying out some of the new Fluid scaling features of Adobe Muse and I'm having some difficulties keeping the page looking good after using dynamic fluid scaling on a large picture.

Let me show you what I mean.
In this example, the site is at it's max width, so everything is positioned correctly (the large picture you see uses fuid width and height scaling):
[Example of site at full size (correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzpli.jpg)

However, if the window is scaled to a smaller width, the large image shrinks correctly, but leaves the text and red horizontal bar behind, so they are incorrectly positioned (leaving a large amount of white space between the bottom of the pic and the top of the red bar): [Example of site at smaller width (incorrect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCYzh.jpg)

So is it possible to automaticaly adjust the position of elements which are placed below an image which scales fluidly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the end.

Seem that you have to make sure that the items are in the correct order in the Layers window (Image at the top, text in descending order below it).